# c# how to gettype from any Datatable

Tags: c#, reflection, datatable

I have googled to solve this problem but I am not successful. I am gettin DataTable from any source like this:

**Name    Surname**

Alex        Desouza

Kim         Hook

This is very simple datatable. I want to gettype from datatable as reflections.

```
    DataTable dt=from any source; 
    Type type=dt.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties=type.GetProperties(); 

foreach(var p in properties) 
{
Console.WriteLine(p.Name)
}
```

Output must be Name , Surnama . How to do it . Thanks 
 **Note**:I want to use reflection.Is there a Conversation for Datatable columns name to class propery(Name,Surname).

Comment: I want to use . Property.GetValue(...) for each item in datatable.

Comment: Here you might need one class object having properties `Name` and `Surname` with valid dataType and then you can cast `DataRow` values and able to set class properties with `Convert.ChangeType`.

Comment: My Datatable is changeble colums. Columns will grows up day by day.

Comment: there is no reason to use reflection here.it's just **nonsense**

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the column names then you would loop through the Columns collection of the DataTable and get the ColumnName of each one.

```
foreach (DataColumn column in myDataTable.Columns)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
    {
        var valueByColumn = row[column];
        var valueByColumnName = row[column.ColumnName];

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I ama try to identify cell values by using columns name like.Property.GetValue(foreach row)

Comment: You seem to be trying to make this harder than it is.  This is not a place to use Reflection.  You can use PropertyDescriptors, which is what is used in data-binding, but that's not Reflection and I don't see why you would want to anyway.  See the code example I have added to my answer, which shows how to get field values by column or column name.